# How to echo a sum of a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php

So I've got this Example for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/mwpmk9kk/1/

As you can see, i summarize the Values of all checkboxes into one readonly input field.

Now i want to echo the Value of all selected Checkboxes into an .php-Site after submitting it (method="post").

I already tried it with `echo $_POST['price'];` but that did not work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you placed the <input> tag inside the <form> tag?

Comment: what does `print_r($_POST)` show?

Comment: Kumar: Yes, it is. @Sean print_r($_POST['price'];  was the solution for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "<BR />";
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
print "DATA: <pre>";
var_dump($data);
var_dump($_POST);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

If the raw input ($data) is not empty have a look at your php.ini and check these paramters

```
enable_post_data_reading    "1" PHP_INI_PERDIR  Available since PHP 5.4.0
post_max_size   "8M"    PHP_INI_PERDIR  PHP_INI_SYSTEM in PHP <= 4.2.3. Available since PHP 4.0.3.
```

A frequent error is post_max_size=x**MB** instead of post_max_size=x**M**

Answer (score 0):

Try this... I've tested in a self submitting form like below and the $_POST['price'] is showing the value of the price in the text field.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['price'])){print_r($_POST['price']); }
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="checkbox" id="cb0" onclick="UpdateCost()" name="Example1" value="5"> Text 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" onclick="UpdateCost()" name="Example2" value="10"> Text 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" onclick="UpdateCost()" name="Example3" value="15"> Text 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb3" onclick="UpdateCost()" name="Example4" value="20"> Text 4<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb4" onclick="UpdateCost()" name="Example5" value="25"> Text 5<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb5" onclick="UpdateCost()" name="Example6" value="30"> Text 6<br /><br />

<input type="text" id="totalcost" name="price" placeholder="Price" readonly size="5" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

hope this helps.